# How to state 2 or more different consequences if an if statement condition is true?

Tags: php, if-statement

I would like to have 2 things happen if an if statement condition is met. If isset is true the variable $value will equal 1. The problem is that I also want the value of a session variable `$_SESSION['counter']` to increment by 1, but I am unsure of the syntax.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION ['counter']=0;

function checkbox_boolean ($name){

if (isset($_POST[$name]))   $slot1 = '1'; $_SESSION['counter']++; else $slot1='0';

}
```

Comment: If you are unsure, then start reading some basic PHP tutorials. And if you don't want to read: "try & error"

Comment: Rizier123 I had already done so, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work and its a better solution:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['counter']=0;

function checkbox_boolean ($name){   
   $slot1=0;
  if(isset($_POST[$name])){
     $slot1 = 1;
     $_SESSION['counter']++;
  }

} 
?>
```

Comment: Definitely easier to read, which counts for a lot in my book. Considering that is was originally presented in a function, might it be better to show that and not leave $slot1 out on a limb.

Comment: edited the code ...take a look again

Comment: Many thanks boomby and Bigscar....I really appreciate it!                                                                                                     Rizier123 - I'm sure you asked questions when you were stating out yourself. I have spent a fair bit of time doing study and trying to find the answer myself before asking.